# Azure Web App Service Websockets using Websocket Sharp

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, azure-web-app-service, websocket-sharp

I'm using the WebsocketSharp net-standard library to create a websocket server. In my Web App Service, **Websockets are ENABLED. Always on is ENABLED.** When I run this server locally, I am able to use it with zero issues. As soon as I deploy to Azure Web App Service, I end up getting an error which says that I am accessing a forbidden port:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The underlying listener has failed to start.
 ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()
   at WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.startReceiving()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.startReceiving()
   at WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.start(ServerSslConfiguration sslConfig)
   at WebSocketSharp.Server.WebSocketServer.Start()
   at socket_uph.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\CFarley\source\repos\socket-uph\Program.cs:line 25
```

My code so far is:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wssv = new WebSocketServer(80);
        wssv.AddWebSocketService<ClientService>("/client");
        wssv.AddWebSocketService<DataService>("/data");
        wssv.Start();  //LINE 25
        while (true)
        {}
    }
}
```

When I publish, the build and publish succeed, but the application fails to start due to the above error.

Comment: Does your WebSocketServer program is webjob?

Comment: Seeing that you have asked two questions about websocket in a row, what language do you want to use to implement websocket? I saw that you were from python before, and now this post is from C#. If the problem has not been solved, what language do you want to use, we can provide targeted help and quickly solve your problem.

Comment: The websocket server is a Web App Service, not a webjob. The language was not particularly important to me so long as I was familiar with it and it worked. I ended up using Socket.IO in JS to implement my server. I'm not deleting either question due to the fact that both of these are still valid questions imo.

Comment: @Carson Have you finally solved this issue?

Comment: No, I haven't had any luck with this.

Comment: You can't listen on port 80 in Azure Web Apps. There's already a web server running listening on that port (in the infrastructure). Are you running on windows or linux?

Also consider:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/web-pubsub/

Comment: @davidfowl Thanks David! The original app is using [Websocket-Sharp](http://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/) and adheres to .NET Standard 2.0. The reason why I had to resort to it is because I want to create an API for a "cloud" enabled printer (Zebra) to uses websockets to connect to my server (potentially hosted in Azure) in order to invoke actions like printing remotely using the API.

Comment: Is it this? https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/webservices/content/Weblink%20WebSocket%20Endpoint%20Configuration.pdf

Comment: Yes! Exactly that!